# how to have postgres ignore inserts with a duplicate key but keep going

Tags: sql, postgresql, clojure, sql-insert, hugsql

I am inserting record data in a collection in memory into postgres and want the database to ignore any record that already exists in the database (by virtue of having the same primary key) but keep going with the rest of my inserts.

I'm using clojure and hugsql, btw, but I'm guessing the answer might be language agnostic.

As I'm essentially treating the database as a set in this way I may be engaging in an antipattern.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're using Postgres 9.5 or newer (which I assume you are, since it was released back in January 2016), there's a very useful `ON CONFLICT` cluase you can use:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, col1, col2)
VALUES (123, 'some_value', 'some_other_value')
ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to solve this for an early version of Postgres so instead of having a single INSERT statement with muliple rows, I used multiple INSERT statements and just ran all of them in a script and made sure that an error would not stop the script (I used Adminer with "stop on error" unchecked) so that the ones that don't throw an error are executed and then all of the new entries got inserted.